# how to read a .ptn file from java

Tags: java

Any one knows what .ptn file is and how to open that, just got the file from client and couldnt able to figure out what is this , searched a lot but no luck .

Also have the requirement from client that
my application should read this .ptn file from Java

is this possible ?

thanks

Comment: try searching. There are many sites that list possible files

Comment: http://filext.com/file-extension/PTN

Comment: can always try opening it notepad and seeing if there is a header at the top or something that lists the application that generated the file, if it's readable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems rather obvious, but if a client is paying you to write code to read a file, you're entirely within your rights to ask what the file *is*, and where it comes from. If it's some internal or proprietary format, you can ask for documentation.

Of course, you might start by simply opening the file in a text editor, to see if it's just something trivial.

[This wonderful web site](http://www.wotsit.org/) is a repository of information about file formats; searching "PTN" brings up nothing, unfortunately, which suggests that it's nothing very common.

Comment: "but if a client is paying you to write code to read a file, you're entirely within your rights to ask what the file is" - totally agree.

Comment: Ok, i'll ask the client then ,If its not a common one as u guys said .Thanks